# Cannot call determinedVisibility() never saw a connection for the pid:some value

Tags: android, jscript

In my code from where I call webview activity I added the following statement:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Still it doesn't work for me on Android 5.1.1

My log cat displaying me this:

```
09-02 14:22:05.258 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.obs time:12875631 beginning of system
09-02 14:22:05.311 19661-19675/com.example.obs W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.479ms 09-02 14:22:05.396 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 51.0.2704.81 (code 270408150)
09-02 14:22:05.409 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 5781-5782)
09-02 14:22:05.409 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.81", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.81"
09-02 14:22:05.416 19661-19661/com.example.obs V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {21b37efb}
09-02 14:22:05.416 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "51.0.2704.81", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.81"
09-02 14:22:05.416 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
09-02 14:22:05.438 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
09-02 14:22:05.488 19661-20394/com.example.obs W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
09-02 14:22:05.503 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
09-02 14:22:05.503 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
09-02 14:22:05.528 19661-20396/com.example.obs D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-02 14:22:05.547 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
09-02 14:22:05.547 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
09-02 14:22:05.561 19661-19661/com.example.obs D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
09-02 14:22:05.569 19661-19661/com.example.obs W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
09-02 14:22:05.570 19661-19661/com.example.obs D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
09-02 14:22:05.611 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
09-02 14:22:05.637 19661-20403/com.example.obs E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-02 14:22:05.656 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
09-02 14:22:05.663 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
09-02 14:22:05.664 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
09-02 14:22:05.669 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
09-02 14:22:05.670 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
09-02 14:22:05.675 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
09-02 14:22:05.677 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
09-02 14:22:05.680 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
09-02 14:22:05.680 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/Utils: could not parse size range '64x64-1920X1088'
09-02 14:22:05.683 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
09-02 14:22:05.688 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/Utils: could not parse size range '64x64-1920X1080'
09-02 14:22:05.691 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
09-02 14:22:05.704 19661-20403/com.example.obs I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
09-02 14:22:05.708 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
09-02 14:22:05.710 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
09-02 14:22:05.711 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ffmpeg
09-02 14:22:05.712 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.dts
09-02 14:22:05.714 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
09-02 14:22:05.716 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
09-02 14:22:05.717 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
09-02 14:22:05.718 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
09-02 14:22:05.720 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
09-02 14:22:05.722 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
09-02 14:22:05.726 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vnd.rn-realvideo
09-02 14:22:05.728 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
09-02 14:22:05.730 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/ffmpeg
09-02 14:22:05.732 19661-20403/com.example.obs W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
09-02 14:22:05.736 19661-20396/com.example.obs D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
09-02 14:22:05.863 19661-19795/com.example.obs V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
09-02 14:22:05.866 19661-19795/com.example.obs V/RenderScript: 0x5586157780 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
09-02 14:22:05.889 19661-19661/com.example.obs W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 19661
09-02 14:22:05.890 19661-19661/com.example.obs D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
09-02 14:22:05.894 19661-19661/com.example.obs I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4a1d642 time:12876268
```

Comment: you figure this out? I've run into the same issue